# How to launch code after an amount of time?

Tags: java, timer, schedule, watchdog

I 'm listening rs232Com using Portcom event-listener then generating propertychangelistener for interface controllers and everything works fine.

My new problem is that acquisitions for some sensors (anemometer) can terminate without any particular indication ( Pulse response ) and mostly dependent of bearings used.

The only solution i can see is that after an amount of time without anymore acquisition ( 2000ms ) i would like to end records to avoid recording data due to involuntary sensor handling .

At this point i can stop acquisitions unregistering controller of new message listener list using a button but i would like to do that automatically.

The point that miss me is to create a Timer that could launch a task after his delay timed out.This with a re-init function to feed him at each acquisition, barely the same way a watchdog works.

I started to search on web but i didn't find solutions and moreover which direction to go to

-Timer class
-Using a Thread / Runnable
-Schedule
-Modified watchdog

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't understand your question very well , but if you want to pause for a certain period of time  you should use ```TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);```   or  TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);

Comment: As Jean-Marc Jancovici always says "when you don't understand a problem what you believe to be a solution is drawing from a hat "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of problem, I often go with a custom thread that has a timer as attribute. The thread check its timer regularly and do something when it ends. And in my main I can add time to the timer attribute if I need to continue.

```
 private static class CustomThread extends Thread {
    private static int wait = 1000;
    private int timer = 0;
    
    public DeleteThread(int timer) {
        this.timer = timer;
    }
    
    public void addToTimer(int time) {
        this.timer += time;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(this.timer > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(wait);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.timer -= wait;
        }
        
        //timer as ended
        doSomething();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomThread myThread = new CustomThread(2000);
        myThread.start();

        //someCode

        //Here I need my thread to continue for 1000 more
        myThread.addToTimer(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Merci ! je l'ai passé en runnable et ajouté une progressBar , mais c'est exactement la base que je cherchais